# REST API data.d.results property error

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, sharepoint-rest-api, error

I am trying to loop through my SharePoint list items retrieved using REST API but I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ID' of undefined

```
function onQuerySucceeded(data) {
    var items = data.d.results
    console.log(items)
    var listItems = ''
    for (var x = 0; x <= items.length; x++) {
        listItems += '<tr>'
        listItems += '<td>' + items[x].ID + '</td>'  //<---Error here
        listItems += '<td>' + items[x].ID + '</td>'
        listItems += '<td>' + items[x].ID + '</td>'
        listItems += '<td>' + items[x].ID + '</td>'
        listItems += '</tr>'
    }
    document.getElementById("service").appendChild(listItems)
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me it looks like you are getting an error because you are letting your indexing variable reach the full `length` of the results array:

```
for (var x = 0; x <= items.length; x++) {
```

Arrays use a zero-based index, so the last possible index is actually one less than the "length" of the array.  Try changing that to:

```
for (var x = 0; x < items.length; x++) {
```

Also, if the error is happening on the very first pass through the loop, it's possible that you had no results from your query.  If that's the case, `data.d.results` will be an empty array, and even index `0` will be undefined.  As Ganesh Sanap suggested, try putting a check in to make sure you have results.  I would go even one step further than that check, to also check the length of the results array and make sure it's not empty:

```
if (data.d && data.d.results && data.d.results.length > 0) {
```

This is why I personally prefer to use `forEach` loops rather than explicit `for` loops whenever possible, because `forEach` loops very gracefully handle the case when the array to be iterated over is empty.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this code:

```
function onQuerySucceeded(data) {
    if(data.d && data.d.results) {
        var items = data.d.results;
        var listItems = "";

        for (var x = 0; x < items.length; x++) {
            listItems += '<tr>';
            listItems += '<td>' + items[x].ID + '</td>';
            listItems += '<td>' + items[x].Title + '</td>';
            listItems += '</tr>';
        }
        document.getElementById("service").appendChild(listItems);
    }
}
```